# Add two variables to a row number

Tags: vba, variables, excel, row

I am new to vba excel and i am mixing between this language and the C language. I need to create a **for loop** that, for example, we have **cell A5**, in next loop the cell row changes to **A(5+j+k)**, **j** initially is **0**, but at end of the loop its **j=j+5**. and **k** is another variable that depends on another loop as well. Can you please tell me how to write this: `A(5+j+k)`  in vba?
to be clearer, my code is not yet right but its more or less like this:

```
For i = 1 To 3

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
j = 0

Range("A5+j").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "XXX"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "YYY"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

j = j + 5

Next i
```

I have finally got the answer for this question, and thought of sharing it here because i currently can't answer my own question so quickly. So, i needed the syntax of writing

```
A(5+i+j)
```

it is simple, i will give a small example to let you know how it works:

```
For i = 0 To 5
   For j = 2 To 6
     Cells(5+i+j,1).Value= "whatever i want to write here"
   Next j
Next i
```

Cheers,
Hawk

Comment: Shall not "j = 0" be outside of the loop?

Comment: actually there is another loop inside this for loop, but i just want to know how to add these variables to the original row number of the cell. I think what you provided is just the offset. See, for example A5 is the original cell, when in loop 2, the cell would be **A(5+2+5)** which is A12. disregarding the random numbers I put here, how is the syntax for adding these numbers to the original cell number to get a new cell number based on those variables?

Answer (score 0):

To move nToTheRight cell to the right from the selected cell:

```
Dim nToTheRight : nToTheRight = j+k
ActiveCell.Offset(0,nToTheRight).Select
```